# imagecrop() alternative for PHP < 5.5

Tags: gd, php-5.4, php-5.5

A simple question motivated by a curiosity, with probably a complex answer: Is it possible to emulate the new PHP 5.5 imagecrop() in earlier versions, like 5.4, by combining other GD functions?

Awn.. But without the imagecrop() [black line bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67447), please. :p

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should be a drop-in replacement for `imagecrop()` (without the bug...):

```
function mycrop($src, array $rect)
{
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($rect['width'], $rect['height']);
    imagecopy(
        $dest,
        $src,
        0,
        0,
        $rect['x'],
        $rect['y'],
        $rect['width'],
        $rect['height']
    );

    return $dest;
}
```

Usage:

```
$img = mycrop($img, ['x' => 10, 'y' => 10, 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100]);
```

Note that the bug is apparently fixed in [PHP 5.6.12](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.12).

Comment: Apparently perfect, but because this problem is not really mine I'll pass the solution ahead before mark your answer.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted but using my own criteria, since this solution was not for a problem of mine and the person in question didn't give me the proper feedback. On behalf of this person, I thank you.