# PHP: Black strip on image while using GD library

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I have a little problem with GD library in PHP - I resize image and then I want crop it to 320px (width) / 240px (height). Let me say that resized image is 320px/300px. When I crop it, a 1-px black strip appears on the bottom of the image - I don't know why.
I'm using `imagecrop`, `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagecopyresampled`

Here's the example:

[image]

Thanks for your time.

**The code**

```
$filename = '../store/projects/project-123.jpg';
$mime = mime_content_type($filename);
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($filename);

$prop = $w / $h;
$new_w = 0;
$new_h = 0;

if ($prop <= 4/3) {
    $new_w = 320;
    $new_h = (int)floor($h*($new_w/$w));
} else {
    $new_h = 240;
    $new_w = (int)floor($w*($new_h/$h));
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w, $new_h);

if (strcmp($mime,'image/png') == 0) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $source = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
} else {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
}

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $w, $h);

$filename = '../store/projects-thumbs/project-123.jpg';

$crop_data = array('x' => 0 , 'y' => 0, 'width' => 320, 'height'=> 240);
$thumb = imagecrop($thumb, $crop_data);

imagejpeg($thumb, $filename, 100);  


imagedestroy($thumb);
imagedestroy($source);
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I edited my post – the code is above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imagecrop()` has a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67447) that causes the black bottom border to be added.

You can work around the problem using `imagecopyresized()`.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26732115/3775731) to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722811/imagecrop-alternative-for-php-5-5) asking for an `imagecrop()` alternative.